# smoothstep() returns different values for "identical" arguments

Tags: glsl, shader, intel

Running a Surface Laptop 3 with Intel® Iris® Plus Graphics (driver version **30.0.101.1191**). Perhaps I'm facing a bug in Intel's shader compiler. Though, I have limited experience of shaders in general, so perhaps the behavior below is expected.

Head over to https://www.shadertoy.com/new and try the shader below. For some reason, defining a `float d = 1.0` seems to produce different results compared to a compile-time constant of `1.0`.

```c
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    float d = 1.0;
    
    // WHY this returns 1?
#if 1
    float x = smoothstep(0.0, 0.0, d);
#else
    // Whereas this returns 0?
    float x = smoothstep(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    // OR this for that matter:
    // float x = smoothstep(0.000000000000001, 0.0, d);
#endif
        
    fragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0) * x;
}
```

Thus, `smoothstep(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)` returns 0 but the equivalent `smoothstep(0.0, 0.0, d)` returns 1. Why?

Comment: Stepping between `0.0` and `0.0` is undefined behavior. The implementation is probably compensating for a divide-by-zero error. Results are also undefined if the first parameter is greater than the second.

Comment: Undefined or not, the arguments are identical and produce two different results. How is that possible? Suddenly `float d = 1.0` does not equal `1.0`?

Comment: Because it's **undefined**. You're lucky the thing doesn't crater your video driver and TDR. A longer answer is that you're clamping positive infinity to `1` and negative infinity to `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`smoothstep` requires that the first parameter `edge0` is strictly less than the second parameter `edge1`. The results are undefined when `edge0 >= edge1`.

The reason behind this is pretty simple. From the GL docs (https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/smoothstep.xhtml)

The code looks something like this:

```
genType t;  /* Or genDType t; */
t = clamp((x - edge0) / (edge1 - edge0), 0.0, 1.0);
return t * t * (3.0 - 2.0 * t);
```

Note the denominator,

```
(edge1 - edge0)
```

If those values are equal, there's a divide-by-zero. So, your implementation is returning a `0` or a `1` since it can't throw an exception, because it's C.

Edit:

On the question of "why is it returning 0 or 1:" The sample implementation from the GL docs clamps the result from 0 to 1. If `edge0 > edge1`, the resulting negative value will be clamped to `0`. If `edge0 == edge1`, divide-by-zero results in positive infinity, which is clamped to `1`.

But, that's all speculation, since the *actual implmentation* in your system's GL implementation is a black box. For cases where `edge0 >= edge1`, the result is undefined and should be ignored.

Comment: Certainly clarifies things a bit. Still, I don't see how the third parameter can produce different results for the exact same value. My only guess is that the optimizer takes a different path when the argument is a local variable.